# Conteo total de elementos especificos en listas anidadas

Tags: python, lista, bucle-for, diccionarios

Hice un diccionario donde cada letra(clave) me da un trío de letras (valor):

```
basesNitro={"A":["G","C","U"],
            "R":["A","G","A"],
            "N":["A","A","U"],
            "D":["G","A","U"],
            "C":["U","G","C"],
            "F":["U","U","U"],
            "G":["G","G","C"],
            "E":["G","A","A"],
            "Q":["C","A","G"],
            "H":["C","A","U"],
            "I":["A","U","U"],
            "L":["U","U","A"],
            "K":["A","A","A"],
            "P":["C","C","U"],
            "S":["U","C","U"],
            "Y":["U","A","U"],
            "T":["A","C","U"],
            "W":["U","G","G"],
            "V":["G","U","A"],
            "M":["A","U","G"],
            "stop":["U","A","A"]
            }
```

la lista problema la separé letra por letra para poder compararla con el diccionario :

```
Sec1=list("AGEKGKKIFVQKCSQCHTVCSQCHTVEKGGKHKTGPNEKGKKIFVQKCSQCHTVLHGLFGRKTGQA")
print(Sec1)
```

---

```
['A', 'G', 'E', 'K', 'G', 'K', 'K', 'I', 'F', 'V', 'Q', 'K', 'C', 'S', 'Q', 'C', 'H', 'T', 'V', 'C', 'S', 'Q', 'C', 'H', 'T', 'V', 'E', 'K', 'G', 'G', 'K', 'H', 'K', 'T', 'G', 'P', 'N', 'E', 'K', 'G', 'K', 'K', 'I', 'F', 'V', 'Q', 'K', 'C', 'S', 'Q', 'C', 'H', 'T', 'V', 'L', 'H', 'G', 'L', 'F', 'G', 'R', 'K', 'T', 'G', 'Q', 'A']
```

cree otra lista llamada "rna" que contenía el resultado de esa comparación pero me sale como una lista de listas anidadas:

```
["['G', 'C', 'U']", "['G', 'G', 'C']", "['G', 'A', 'A']",
 "['A', 'A', 'A']", "['G', 'G', 'C']", "['A', 'A', 'A']",  
 "['A', 'A', 'A']", "['A', 'U', 'U']", "['U', 'U', 'U']", 
 "['G', 'U', 'A']", "['C', 'A', 'G']", "['A', 'A', 'A']", 
 "['U', 'G', 'C']", "['U', 'C', 'U']", "['C', 'A', 'G']", 
 "['U', 'G', 'C']", "['C', 'A', 'U']", "['A', 'C', 'U']", 
 "['G', 'U', 'A']", "['U', 'G', 'C']", "['U', 'C', 'U']", 
 "['C', 'A', 'G']", "['U', 'G', 'C']", "['C', 'A', 'U']", 
 "['A', 'C', 'U']", "['G', 'U', 'A']", "['G', 'A', 'A']", 
 "['A', 'A', 'A']", "['G', 'G', 'C']", "['G', 'G', 'C']", 
 "['A', 'A', 'A']", "['C', 'A', 'U']", "['A', 'A', 'A']", 
 "['A', 'C', 'U']", "['G', 'G', 'C']", "['C', 'C', 'U']", 
 "['A', 'A', 'U']", "['G', 'A', 'A']", "['A', 'A', 'A']", 
 "['G', 'G', 'C']", "['A', 'A', 'A']", "['A', 'A', 'A']", 
 "['A', 'U', 'U']", "['U', 'U', 'U']", "['G', 'U', 'A']", 
 "['C', 'A', 'G']", "['A', 'A', 'A']", "['U', 'G', 'C']", 
 "['U', 'C', 'U']", "['C', 'A', 'G']", "['U', 'G', 'C']", 
 "['C', 'A', 'U']", "['A', 'C', 'U']", "['G', 'U', 'A']", 
 "['U', 'U', 'A']", "['C', 'A', 'U']", "['G', 'G', 'C']", 
 "['U', 'U', 'A']", "['U', 'U', 'U']", "['G', 'G', 'C']", 
 "['A', 'G', 'A']", "['A', 'A', 'A']", "['A', 'C', 'U']", 
 "['G', 'G', 'C']", "['C', 'A', 'G']", "['G', 'C', 'U']"]
```

Lo que busco, es contar cuantas "C" y "G" se encuentran en toda la lista pero solo cuenta si existe o no la presencia de "C" o "G" y no cuenta realmente los valores presentes en las listas anidadas.

Así realicé el conteo:

```
conteoG=0
for i in rna:
    if "C" in i:
        conteoC += 1
    if "G" in i:
        conteoG += 1
print(conteoC)
print(conteoG)
```

Me da 37 de "C" y 32 de "G" cuando deben ser 38 y 41 respectivamente.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El operador de pertenencia `in` simplemente retorna `True` si un determinado objeto esta en un contenedor, independientemente de cuantas veces este. Para contar la aparición de cada base por codon tienes que iterar sobre cada sublista:

```
conteoC=0
conteoG=0

for codon in rna:
    for base in codon:
        if base == "C":
            conteoC += 1
        elif base == "G":
            conteoG += 1

print(conteoC)
print(conteoG)
```

Otra opción mas simple es usar los métodos `str.count` / `list.count` para que hagan el trabajo del segundo ciclo anidado:

```
conteoC=0
conteoG=0

for codon in rna:
    conteoC += codon.count("C")
    conteoG += codon.count("G")

print(conteoC)
print(conteoG)
```

Es menos eficiente en el sentido de que iteramos (`count` itera implícitamente) sobre cada codon una vez por base a contar, mientras que en el primer código se itera una sola vez.

Cambien usando `sum` y un generador:

```
conteoC = sum(codon.count("C") for codon in rna)
conteoG = sum(codon.count("G") for codon in rna)

print(conteoC)
print(conteoG)
```

---

Una observación, tu lista resultado tal y como se muestra en la pregunta, no es una lista de listas sino una lista de cadenas (que representan una lista). Es decir, tienes:

```
["['G', 'C', 'U']", "['G', 'G', 'C']", ...]
```

en vez de

```
[['G', 'C', 'U'], ['G', 'G', 'C'], ...],
```

No dices como generas tu lista resultado, pero seria simplemente algo como:

```
rna = [basesNitro[amin] for amin in Sec1]
```

Por ultimo, si vas a terminar contando el numero de apariciones de cada base, una forma muy eficiente y simple es usar `collections.Counter`:

```
from collections import Counter


basesNitro = {
    "A": ["G", "C", "U"],
    "R": ["A", "G", "A"],
    "N": ["A", "A", "U"],
    "D": ["G", "A", "U"],
    "C": ["U", "G", "C"],
    "F": ["U", "U", "U"],
    "G": ["G", "G", "C"],
    "E": ["G", "A", "A"],
    "Q": ["C", "A", "G"],
    "H": ["C", "A", "U"],
    "I": ["A", "U", "U"],
    "L": ["U", "U", "A"],
    "K": ["A", "A", "A"],
    "P": ["C", "C", "U"],
    "S": ["U", "C", "U"],
    "Y": ["U", "A", "U"],
    "T": ["A", "C", "U"],
    "W": ["U", "G", "G"],
    "V": ["G", "U", "A"],
    "M": ["A", "U", "G"],
    "stop": ["U", "A" ,"A"]
}

Sec1 = ['A', 'G', 'E', 'K', 'G', 'K', 'K', 'I', 'F', 'V', 'Q', 'K', 'C', 'S', 'Q', 'C', 'H', 'T', 'V', 'C', 'S', 'Q', 'C', 'H', 'T', 'V', 'E', 'K', 'G', 'G', 'K', 'H', 'K', 'T', 'G', 'P', 'N', 'E', 'K', 'G', 'K', 'K', 'I', 'F', 'V', 'Q', 'K', 'C', 'S', 'Q', 'C', 'H', 'T', 'V', 'L', 'H', 'G', 'L', 'F', 'G', 'R', 'K', 'T', 'G', 'Q', 'A']

rna = [basesNitro[amin] for amin in Sec1]
base_count = Counter(base for codon in rna for base in codon)

conteoC = base_count.get("C", 0)
conteoG = base_count.get("G", 0)

print(base_count) #Counter({'A': 71, 'U': 48, 'G': 41, 'C': 38}
print(conteoC) # 38
print(conteoG) # 41
```

o si quieres asignar todo a variables de una vez:

```
countA, countC, countG, countU = (base_count.get(base, 0) for base in "ACGU")
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, si justo hacía que imprimiera la lista que creí que era una lista de listas y me salían 990 caracteres, lo corregí y usé el ultimo código para el contador solo solicitando imprimir el % de C y de G y quedaron como calculé a mano.

Muchisimas gracias!!